# Intent not accepting in setOnClickListener

Tags: android

I am trying to call another activity (`Intent`) inside setOnClickListner, but it is not called.What Should I do?
My code looks like this:

```
ButtonGoToLoginActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Finishing current Main Activity.
        finish();
        // Opening the Login Activity using Intent.
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: reply if it works.. have updated my answer..

Comment: finish() should be after the startactivity.

Comment: Same issue. Not accepting Intent. Showing intent in red color "cannot resolve symbol"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An intent object couldn't be created after the finish. Try it before `finish();`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent); 
finish();
```

**Update:** In your case import the intent like this.

```
import android.content.Intent
```

Comment: Same issue. Not accepting Intent. Showing intent in red color "cannot resolve symbol"

Comment: `alt+enter` and import the class

Comment: take your cursor over Intent and then use `alt+enter` update if it works..

Comment: i know that, no import option... only showing "create class intent" and "create enum intent" etc options

Comment: try rebuilding the project ..any other red mark other than intent ??

Comment: i rebuild it but no effect. no there are no other errors

Comment: It worked. I updated my android studio to 3.. may be that was the issue..anyways Thankyou so Much :)

Answer (score 0):

As your code implies, you are calling `finish()` method before calling your new activity. In other words, the following lines of code will never run:

```
   // Opening the Login Activity using Intent.
   Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

In order to solve the problem, add `finish()` method after above block of code.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to clean and rebuild your project. Also delete the already build apks and then the issue might be resolved and you will be allowed to import 
import android.content.Intent  for using Intent.